# Update model value from component

Tags: dart, angular-dart

Below is code of dart angular component for delayed validation. It means I set changes in different place as from my model object, after validating  whole collection of dart's doubles modify main model. Now I want refactor it to modify model immediately. Just input field for decimal number should update business model fields. How can I pass Dart's double to material input in my Component to receive updates in business model existing in parent relation co my angular component?

```
@Component(
selector: 'editor',
template: '''
<form><material-input 
    [(ngModel)]="val" 
    type="number" 
    (change)="onChange(\$event)" 
    floatingLabel 
    label="pole"
    #inp1="ngForm"
>
</material-input></form>
''',
directives: const [
  CORE_DIRECTIVES,
  materialDirectives,
  formDirectives,
  materialNumberInputDirectives,
  materialInputDirectives
])
class Editor {

 @Input()
 double val;
 @Input()
 int i;
 @Input()
 Map<String, String> colector;

 void onChange(double value) {
  colector[i.toString()] = value.toString();
 }
}
```

used as :

```
<editor [val]="o2.num" [colector]="myColector" [i]="i"></editor>
```

Comment: The component only has one input. What do you mean with "particular input"?

Comment: One input.  Input moved from parent component into new component.

Comment: Add more <material-tags> for the `int i` and however you want to present the map?